# How to insert new record in AdventureWorks2016 which uses BusinessIdentityId

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

This question was asked [on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9dd263a0-aac3-45c1-9dd6-c60a2095cbe9/businessentityid-need-help-understanding?forum=sqlserversamples) but never actually answered.

AdventureWorks2016 uses a "BusinessEntityId" as the primary key for several tables.  It is NOT an identity column, yet it is unique among all the tables where it is used, such as Sales.Store.

So the question is, where is the ID to come from when saving a new record?  It seems clumsy to have to call a stored procedure to get the next valid ID.

For example, if I am using Entity Framework, I do not see how it's going to work at all, yet it was supposedly done specifically to showcase inheritance at work in EF.

I have found this type of structure useful, but don't see how to actually make it work with EF Core.

```
CREATE TABLE [Sales].[Store](
    [BusinessEntityID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [dbo].[Name] NOT NULL,
    [SalesPersonID] [int] NULL,
    [Demographics] [xml](CONTENT [Sales].[StoreSurveySchemaCollection]) NULL,
    [rowguid] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Store_BusinessEntityID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED





 CREATE TABLE [Person].[Person](
    [BusinessEntityID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PersonType] [nchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [NameStyle] [dbo].[NameStyle] NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [FirstName] [dbo].[Name] NOT NULL,
    [MiddleName] [dbo].[Name] NULL,
    [LastName] [dbo].[Name] NOT NULL,
    [Suffix] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [EmailPromotion] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AdditionalContactInfo] [xml](CONTENT [Person].[AdditionalContactInfoSchemaCollection]) NULL,
    [Demographics] [xml](CONTENT [Person].[IndividualSurveySchemaCollection]) NULL,
    [rowguid] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Person_BusinessEntityID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [BusinessEntityID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Please, provide a tabla as sample.

Comment: @H.Herzl Table Structure added

Comment: Sales.Store table contains a foreign key with name FK_Store_BusinessEntity_BusinessEntityID, Table Person.BusinessEntity contains an identity column, so I guess you need to save in that table before to insert in child tables, that makes sense?

Comment: @H.Herzl Yes, you are correct.  I missed that there is a Person.BusinessEntity table. Thank you.  If you want to post as an answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AdventureWorks2016 database there is a table with name Person.BusinessEntity, this table contains an identity column.

Reviewing Sales.Store table, there is a foreign key for Person.BusinessEntity table.

So, first you need to save on Person.BusinessEntity table and then save in child table, Sales.Store in this case.

Inside of EF Core, you need to add the configuration for your entities, configuration for Person.BusinessEntity table includes an identity and Sales.Store needs to have a required property.

In save you can use a transaction, using Database property in DbContext instance.

If you want to generate ef core objects from existing database you can use scaffolding or another tool, for example [CatFactory](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1160615/Generating-Code-for-EF-Core-with-CatFactory)

Let me know if this is useful.